# How do I write to a DIBits structure in Go?

Tags: go, unsafe-pointers

I'm using a w32 library to allow me to do Windowing with the Go language. I'm not quite sure what to do with an `unsafe.Pointer` that will allow me to start setting pixel values in the pixel buffer.

I use an `unsafe.Pointer`, because that's what the w32 library expects me to pass in the CreateDIBSection function.

```
var p unsafe.Pointer
bitmap := w32.CreateDIBSection( srcDC, &bmi, w32.DIB_RGB_COLORS, &p, w32.HANDLE(0), 0 )
```

That code succeeds and gives me a pointer to the memory location where the DIBBits are stored. How can I use that to write values?

```
p[idx] = 0xff
```

will give me an error `type unsafe.Pointer does not allow indexing`. I've read the relevant docs on the unsafe.Pointer, but can't figure out how to treat it as a byte buffer that I can write into.

I'm new to Go and have worked through a lot of the examples at [gobyexample.com](http://gobyexample.com), but cannot figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a matter of casting the unsafe.Pointer back to an array (which is indexable) in the proper way.

After trying various casts, this is the one that worked (assuming `wid` and `hgt` are each declare as `const`):

```
pixels := (*[wid*hgt*4]uint8)(ptr)
```

then I was able to change them with:

```
pixels[(y*wid+x)*4+0] = 0x00 // Blue
pixels[(y*wid+x)*4+1] = 0x00 // Green
pixels[(y*wid+x)*4+2] = 0x00 // Red
```